# vimscript: switch to buffer by filename path

Tags: path, buffer, filenames, vim

I have a vimscript which needs to switch to a particular buffer. That buffer will be specified by either full path, partial path, or just its name.

For example:

I am in the directory `/home/user/code` and I have 3 vim buffers open `foo.py` `src/foo.py` and `src/bar.py`.

- If the script was told to switch to buffer `/home/user/code/foo.py` it would switch to buffer `foo.py`.
- If it were told to switch to `user/code/src/foo.py` it would switch to buffer `src/foo.py`
- If it were told to switch to `foo.py` it would switch to buffer `foo.py`
- If it were told to swith to `bar.py` it would switch to buffer `src/bar.py`

The simplest solution I can see is to somehow get a list of the buffers stored in a variable and use trial and error.

It would be nice if the solution was cross platform, but it needs to at least run on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bufname()` / `bufnr()` functions can lookup loaded buffers by partial filename. You can anchor the match to the end by appending a `$`, like this:

```
echo bufnr('/src/foo.py$')
```

Comment: *wry grin*  I knew vim would have a function to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this using python in a vimscript. With python I was able to get the names of all the buffers from `vim.buffers[i].name` and used `os.path` and `os.sep` to process which buffer to switch to.

In the end, I decided that it would be more helpful for it to refuse to do anything if the buffer it was requested to switch to was ambiguous.

Here it is:

```
"Given a file, full path, or partial path, this will try to change to the
"buffer which may match that file. If no buffers match, it returns 1. If
"multiple buffers match, it returns 2. It returns 0 on success
function s:GotoBuffer(buf)
python << EOF
import vim, os
buf = vim.eval("a:buf")

#split the paths into lists of their components and reverse.
#e.g. foo/bar/baz.py becomes ['foo', 'bar', 'baz.py']
buf_path = os.path.normpath(buf).split(os.sep)[::-1]
buffers = [os.path.normpath(b.name).split(os.sep)[::-1] for b in vim.buffers]
possible_buffers = range(len(buffers))

#start eliminating incorrect buffers by their filenames and paths
for component in xrange(len(buf_path)):
    for b in buffers:
        if len(b)-1 >= component and b[component] != buf_path[component]:
            #This buffer doesn't match. Eliminate it as a posibility.
            i = buffers.index(b)
            if i in possible_buffers: possible_buffers.remove(i)

if len(possible_buffers) > 1: vim.command("return 2")
#delete the next line to allow ambiguous switching
elif not possible_buffers: vim.command("return 1") 
else:
    vim.command("buffer " + str(possible_buffers[-1] + 1))
EOF
endfunction
```

**EDIT:** The above code seems to have some bugs. I am not going to fix them because there is another answer which is much better.